# channels_presence.Presence.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'auth.User', which is either not installed, or is abstract

Tags: django, django-models, django-channels, django-channels-presence

I am trying to use django channels_presence in my project but my user model is present in another project(microservice architechure) named auth which gives me the error:

```
channels_presence.Presence.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'auth.User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
channels_presence.Presence.user: (fields.E307) The field channels_presence.Presence.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'auth.user', but app 'auth' isn't installed.
```

How do I use channels_presence without User model in the same project?

Comment: I am exactly stuck in the same case, do you have found a workaround ?

Comment: @OlivierArgentieri I had to modify it to fit my use case. You can clone it and make it a Django app in your project. The code is  simple to understand and modify as most of the logic is in models.py